# Linear independence of monomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the monomials {1, x, x$^2$, x$^3$, ...} are linearly independent vectors in C$^∞$$\Bbb{R}$.

I know how to show this for finitely many terms, i.e. {1, x, x$^2$, x$^3$, ..., x$^n$}. I differentiate each side of the following expression n times to show that c$_n$ = 0:

$0$ = c$_0$1 + c$_1$x + c$_2$x$^2$ + ... + c$_n$x$^n$

The process of differentiating is then repeated until all c$_0$ = c$_1$ = ... = c$_n$ = $0$.

How do I show this for infinitely many monomial terms?

Comment: You’re already done. A linear combination from an infinite set of vectors still only involves finitely many vectors. (This kind of confusion is only possible because people are taught calculus before linear algebra...)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ is linearly dependent, i.e., suppose that there exists $k \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $i_1,\dots,i_k \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 = a_1x^{i_1} + \cdots + a_kx^{i_k}$ for some $(a_1,\dots,a_k) \in \mathbb R^k$ other than $(0,\dots,0)$. This of course contradicts the linear independence of $\{1,x\dots,x^M\}$ where $M = \max\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$, as you verified.